# Counting number of elements less than and adding it to the original in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `I1` and `I2`. I am comparing elements of `I2` to elements in `I1` and want to add the number of elements which are less than or equal to it. For example, `11` in `I2` has two two elements less than or equal to it in `I1`. Hence, `2` should be added to `11`. Similarly, for elements `27` and `41` in `I2`. I present the current and expected output.

```
I1=[1,11,13,16,26,30,43,46]

I2=[11,27,41]
I2=[i for i in I2 if I2<=I1]
print("I2 =",I2)
```

The current output is

```
I2 = []
```

The expected output is

```
I2 = [13,32,47]
```

Comment: In your list comprehension, you are making it conditional on a comparison between the two lists. The results of this comparison should never change. What is the thinking here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a counter to see the number and their frequency which is less than current, so to avoid the repetiiton calculation

```
from collections import Counter

I1=[1,11,13,16,26,30,43,46]
I2=[11,27,41]

c1 = Counter(I1)
result = []

for i in I2:
    val = sum(j for v, j in c1.items() if v<=i) + i
    result.append(val)
print(result) # 13 32 47
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the worst-case performance still *O(n^2)*? I can see how it would improve performance though if `I1` contained a lot of duplicates.

Comment: yes, it's O(N*N) when there are unique elements, inorder to imprpove, need to use bisect (provided sorted values), and each node having info how many are lower than it, than it will be O(log n). here is solution for OP understanding in easy way, if performance wise require then it can be done also

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
lst1 = [1,11,13,16,26,30,43,46] 
lst2 = [11,27,41]

lst2 = [a + sum(a>=b for b in lst1) for a in lst2]
print("I2 =", lst2)
```

Output

```
I2 = [13, 32, 47]
```

---

Note: *"Python variables should begin with lowercase letters (preferably ones that aren't easily mistaken for numbers like `1`)"* as [@Chris says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73839103/counting-number-of-elements-less-than-and-adding-it-to-the-original-in-python/73839178?noredirect=1#comment130382474_73839178:%7E:text=Please%20use%20the%20opportunity%20an%20answer%20provides%20to%20demonstrate%20good%20coding%20style.%20Python%20variables%20should%20begin%20with%20lowercase%20letters%20(preferably%20ones%20that%20aren%27t%20easily%20mistaken%20for%20numbers%20like%201)%2C%20and%20some%20whitespace%20would%20make%20this%20much%20more%20readable.).

Comment: Please use the opportunity an answer provides to demonstrate good coding style. Python variables should begin with lowercase letters (preferably ones that aren't easily mistaken for numbers like `1`), and some whitespace would make this much more readable.

Comment: @Chris I can't change them because they are in the OP's post, Instead, I can add an*Note*

Comment: Of course you can change it. If the OP cannot understand the use of better variable names and whitespace, they are in need of assistance beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Chris I don't change them because some times I get downvotes for only changing variable names. Now edited

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised thta nobody mentioned numpy masking yet.

- `data1 <= item` will give you an array of booleans showing where that condition is true/false.
- `(data1 <= item).sum()` takes advantage of how booleans sum to integers in python to count the number of true items. You could use `len(data1[(data1 <= item)])` but it's longer.
- We do that for each item in your second array.

```py
import numpy as np

data1 = np.array([1, 11, 13, 16, 26, 30, 43, 46])
data2 = np.array([11, 27, 41])

smaller_counts = np.array([(data1 <= item).sum() for item in data2])
# >>> [2 5 6]
result = data2 + smaller_counts
# >>> [13 32 47]
```

Answer (score 2):

If `I1` is always sorted and could be very large, you could use binary search for better performance, with the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html):

```
>>> import bisect
>>> [x + bisect.bisect_right(I1, x) for x in I2]
[13, 32, 47]
```

---

*<sub>Thanks to [Psidom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4983450/psidom) for posting this solution in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73839103#comment130382411_73839103).</sub>*